# What virus properties affect their airborne contagiousness?

Tags: virology, influenza, ebola

What properties of a virus affect it's ability to be transmitted by air? I assume it must be able to withstand different temperatures and be smallish in size?

For example why is influenza very easily transmitted by air but the ebola virus is not?

Comment: Your question is very broad. There are multiple factors that determine the infectivity of a virus.